# Python POST using Requests capture Cookie

Tags: python, http, post, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to make a simple Python script that logs into a online "game" and captures the Cookie for future use within the game. This is the code:

```
import requests

def login():
        url = 'https://########/login'
        params = {'username':'######','password':'#####'}
        r = requests.post(url,params=params)
        print r.cookies.keys()
        print r.status_code
        print r.text
login()
```

When running the script, it does print (r.text) as it was a successful login, however cookies came out empty.

For reference, here is a screen capture of a request made frome Iceweasel using TamperData:

[image: screen shot]

And the output of the script (r.text commented out) is:

```
python script2.py 
[]
200
```

What I am missing?

Comment: What does `r.headers` say was returned in the headers? Why are you not using a `requests.Session()` object to persist cookies between requests?

Comment: You could try adding `allow_redirects=False`.

Comment: What does `r.history` show? Are there any redirects? Your screenshot shows the login POST gave a 302, so `requests` would follow the redirect.